# how to get certificates with certain statuses from the GoDaddy API?

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting, godaddy-api

I am working on a powershell project that involves getting expired certificates from GoDaddy's API. How can I do so wihout getting all of the certificates and displaying only the expired ones?

each certificate is displayed as a part in an array. Example:

```
 $SSLcerts[0] = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.godaddy.com/v1/certificates/EXAMPLE' -Method Get -Headers $headers | ConvertFrom-Json
```

and then the entire array gets converted to html.

Comment: (I) if you use ```Invoke-RestMethod``` instead of ```Invoke-WebRequest``` you probably won’t need to pipe it into ```ConvertFrom-Json``` (ii) if the GoDaddy API doesn’t allow you to filter the results server-side you can just pipe the response into ```where-object``` to filter out expired certificates client-side. If you show the structure of the json response (obfuscate sensitive data) you might get some help with what needs to go in the ```where-object```…